# How to Lease a DHCP IP Address for X Number Of Days in Windows 2003 Machine

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

I have a numerous set of windows servers. The requirement of Fixed DHCP IP Address may vary for each server. One IT Guy may ask like i need this DHCP Address for 30 days and another may say i need it for 15 days. How can i configure this kind of DHCP lease from the windows 2003 machine to DHCP Server. Is it Possible?

Comment: We are going to need a lot more detail to answer this, are we talking a client lease or a server lease? Do you control the DHCP server? what is the problem you are running into that you need to worry about DHCP lease times and renewals?

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple matter of changing DHCP Lease duration for the scopes in question. Have a look at the official [Microsoft Technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783573%28WS.10%29.aspx).

If you have varying requirements for different lease lengths on the same subnet, then you have a more unique problem. I'm assuming you are making DHCP reservations for these IP addresses. In that case, it's a simple matter of deleting the reservation and then when the server next reboots or performs a `ipconfig /renew` it will be assigned a new IP.

Make sure that your pool of reserved IPs is cordoned off with an exclusion mask. You will have to test this for yourself, as I cannot access a test DHCP server at this moment, but it may be possible that reservations can hand out IPs that are in an exclusion range. That would allow you to exclude a range of IPs from normal DHCP leases, and yet still give out those "static DHCP addresses" when a specific MAC address requests an IP.

---

**Having said the above**, realize that you are asking DHCP to do something that it was not meant to do and any trouble you run into will be as a result of square pegging a round hole. The better option it so exclude a range of IP space from DHCP leases and then tell people to manually configure an IP address on an interface. When they're done with it, they reconfigure their network interface.